# Error accessing field when updating many to many mapping

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to generate many `Team`s, each of which is composed of multiple `Person` objects, using JPA. I know that I need to manually update both sides of a many-to-many relation, so this is what I try to do.

Here is `Person.java` (with getters and setters omitted for brevity).

```java
/**
 * Represents any person (teaching assistant, student, or other) that exists in this application.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
)
public abstract class Person extends BasicEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String emailAddress;

    /**
     * The list of teams that this person belongs to.
     */
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "team_members",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    )
    private List<Team> teams;

    /**
     * Default constructor for JPA.
     */
    protected Person () {
        this.teams = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new Person.
     * @param firstName The person's first name.
     * @param lastName The person's last name.
     * @param emailAddress The person's email address.
     */
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress) {
        this();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public void assignToTeam(Team team) {
        this.teams.add(team);
        //team.addMember(this);
    }
```

As you can see, in the `assignToTeam` method, I have commented out the 'reflexive' part, where I update the `Team`'s representation of the relation, after updating the `Person`'s own.

Since it is necessary for the scope of this issue, here is `Team.java`.

```java
/**
 * A group consisting of one or more members. Child classes should define P as a sub class of Person to define custom
 * behavior if needed.
 * @param <P> The type of members this group contains.
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(
        strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED
)
public abstract class Team<P extends Person> extends BasicEntity {

    /**
     * The list of members in this group.
     */
    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "team_members",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "team_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    )
    protected List<P> members;

    /**
     * The course that this team belongs to.
     */
    @ManyToOne(
            optional = false
    )
    private Course course;

    /**
     * Default constructor for JPA and initializing list of members for any child classes.
     */
    protected Team() {
        this.members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addMember(P person) {
        if (!this.containsMember(person)) {
            this.members.add(person);
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when I am generating a set of testing data for my application, and I call the following method:

```java
private List<StudentTeam> generateStudentTeams() {
        StudentGenerator studentGenerator = new StudentGenerator(this.getSeed());
        List<StudentTeam> teams = new ArrayList<>(this.studentGroupCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.studentGroupCount; i++) {
            StudentTeam team = new StudentTeam();
            List<Student> students = studentGenerator.generateList(this.studentGroupSize);
            for (Student s : students) {
                s.assignToTeam(team);
            }
            teams.add(team);
        }
        return teams;
    }
```

which results in some errors of the following nature:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field  [private nl.andrewlalis.teaching_assistant_assistant.model.people.TeachingAssistantRole nl.andrewlalis.teaching_assistant_assistant.model.people.TeachingAssistant.role] by reflection for persistent property [nl.andrewlalis.teaching_assistant_assistant.model.people.TeachingAssistant#role] : nl.andrewlalis.teaching_assistant_assistant.model.people.Student@1028bf36`

My question is, how can I properly set both sides of the relation and avoid such an issue?

Comment: There are several reasons for a PropertyAccessException. 

Have you tried annotating Person's "teams" attribute with just @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members") ?

Are the tables generated correctly, with foreign keys?

Comment: @DiegoVictordeJesus Yes, I have verified that all the tables are generated exactly as intended, with foreign keys and so forth. I have even tested the creation of individual objects in this question, all of which work properly.

Answer (score 0):

> If you choose to map the relationship in both directions, then one
>   direction must be defined as the owner and the other must use the
>   **mappedBy** attribute to define its mapping. This also avoids having to
>   duplicate the **JoinTable** information in both places.
>
> If the mappedBy is not used, then the persistence provider will assume
>   there are two independent relationships, and you will end up getting
>   duplicate rows inserted into the join table. If you have a conceptual
>   bi-directional relationship, but have two different join tables in the
>   database, then you must not use the mappedBy, as you need to maintain
>   two independent tables.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Bi-directional_Many_to_Many